# Laravel - set array just with values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I'm trying to send an email to multiple emails, so I did a query to my users tables but the result is an array with keys that don't work `mail->to()`.

I need an array like this: `$owners = ['myoneemail@esomething.com', 'myother@esomething.com','myother2@esomething.com'];` from database.

My query:

```
$owners = DB::table('users')->select('email')->where('active', 1)->where('userType', 1)->get();
```

I also try use `->toArray()` but comes with keys.

Email:

```
Mail::send('email-view', $data, function($message) use ($data, $owners)
{
  $message->from('no-reply@email.pt' , 'FROM');
  $message->to($owners)->subject('subject');

});
```

Comment: please check my answer. it might be resolve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: `$query->where([
    ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
    ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
    [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
    ...
])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$owners = DB::table('users')->where('active', 1)->where('userType', 1)->pluck('email')->toArray();
```

Comment: `lists` is now `pluck`.

Comment: Oh! yes Modified it...@u_mulder. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: returns me Illegal offset type @DarshanJain

Comment: which laravel version you are using @user3242861 ?

Comment: 5.4 @DarshanJain

Comment: Can you try `$lists = User::pluck('email')->toArray();` Let me know if still not work.

Comment: Works! $owners = DB::table('users')->where('active', 1)->where('userType', 1)->pluck('email')->toArray(); Thank you @DarshanJain

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`->pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck), like this:

```
$owners = DB::table('users')->select('email')->where('active', 1)->where('userType', 1)->get();
$emailList = $owners->pluck('email');
```

Comment: Returns me Illegal offset type @Phiter

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the where condition is not proper in your query builder code.
It has to be like:

```
$query->where([
    ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
    ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
    [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
    ...
])
```

> You can use `pluck()` to get the list in Laravel 5.

All collections also serve as iterators, allowing you to loop over them as if they were simple PHP arrays:

```
    foreach ($owners as $owner) {
        echo $owner->filed_name;
        echo $owner->filed_name;
        ...
    }
```

There is no restriction for using the core PHP code while using a PHP framework. You may refer the official [PHP Arrays Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) page to work with the language construct.

If you need to convert JSON to array, use:

> ***json_decode($owners);***

Answer (score 0):

```
$owners = DB::table('users')->where('active', 1)->where('userType', 1)->pluck('email');
```

or

```
    $owners = User::where('active', 1)->where('userType', 1)->pluck('email');
```

here User is your model name